# $f:[a,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=c\in \mathbb{R}$ so $f$ is uniformly continuos in $[a,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

let be $ \ f:[a,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $. Such that f is continuous in $[a,\infty)$ and: $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=c\in \mathbb{R}.$$

then $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,\infty)$.

I would like to know how to prove it by the defininiton of uniform continuity or by sequences characterization of uniform continuity.

Than you so much.

Comment: Note that $|f(x)-c|$ will be $\leq \varepsilon$ for all $x \geq M$ for some $M$ large enough. On the compact interval $[a, M],$ $f$ will be uniformly continuous by the Heine-Cantor theorem. Can you see how to finish now?

Comment: not at all... sorry

Comment: For every $x_1,x_2>M$ you have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$ by the triangle inequality. For every $x_1,x_2\leq M$ you also have that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$ since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,M]$. But this is not enough because you might have $x_1\leq M$ and $x_2>M$. So take an overlap: instead of considering $[a,M]$ consider $[a,M+1]$. You can pick $\delta$ which is small enough to force $|x_1-x_2|<1$. So either $x_1,x_2>M$ and we are done, or $x_1,x_2<M+1$ and we are done, or else $x_1>M+1$ and $x_2<M$ but this can't happen because we force them to be less than distance $1$ apart.

Comment: Thank you shanw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= c$, then there is $A>0$ such that

$$|f(x) -c| < {\epsilon \over 4},\,\,\, \forall x >A.$$

Choose $M>A>0$. Then for every $x,y \in [a,\infty)$ we have

If $x,y \in [a, M]$, then the compactness of the closed interval we have the fact that continuity implies uniformly continuity inside the closed interval.

If $x,y > M$ then

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) -c| + |c -f(y)| < {\epsilon \over 2} < \epsilon.$$

Finally, when $x \in [a,M]$ and $y >M$, we have

$$|f(x) -f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(M)| + |f(M)- c| + |c -f(y)| <\epsilon.$$

Above we assumed $|f(x)-f(M)| < \frac \epsilon 2$ because the uniform continuity inside the closed interval $[a,M]$.

Comment: Than you so much the only think I dont get about the demonstration is What is $\alpha$ in this inequality $|f(M)-c|<\alpha$.

Comment: @PabloGarciaPastor I didn’t write any alpha!

Comment: Let me assume you have meant $\epsilon$ instead of $\alpha$. Since is just a point in the real line and great than A, by the first step in the proof, then we have that $f(M)$ within $\epsilon /2$ from c.

Comment: Oh thank you I thought you have written $A>M$ in the first step. Thank you for the help.